# React and multiple timed events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I am new to working with React and as an exercise have tried to modify the clock example
from [React's splash page](https://facebook.github.io/react/).  The goal is to have the seconds count at one interval and change 
circle's color at a more rapid interval.

I have tried to do this by using `setTimeout` functions for the changes to the circle
and called them from within the `tick` function, but the `setTimeout` calls are not being 
recognized.

Is this an issue with React and the `setInterval` conflicting with the `setTimeout`?
If so what is the best way to achieve offset timed events?

Thank you for your time.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Timer</title>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/babel">

var changed = false;

class GameDisplay extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.colorChange = this.colorChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      secondsElapsed: 0,
    };
  }

  tick(){
    setTimeout(() => this.colorChange(), 250);
    setTimeout(() => this.colorChange(), 250);
    this.colorChange();
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      secondsElapsed: prevState.secondsElapsed + 1,
    }));
  }

  colorChange(){
    var tgt = document.getElementById("heart");
    if (changed){
      tgt.style.fill = "red";
    } else {
      tgt.style.fill = "green";
    }
    changed =  !changed;
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      <h1>Seconds Elapsed: {this.state.secondsElapsed}</h1>
      <svg id="main_disp" width="300" height="300">
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="50" fill="black" />
        <circle id="heart" cx="150" cy="150" r="30" fill="red" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <GameDisplay />
      </div>
    )
  };
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** the reason you see no change is that you have two colorChange executions at the "same time", one overriding the other.

```
setTimeout(() => this.colorChange(), 250);
setTimeout(() => this.colorChange(), 250);
```

**setTimeout** is async and immediately returns so you schedule two colorChange executions after the "same" amount of time. Try to put the second call to timeout after 500ms and it works.

I used quotes on "same time" because setTimeout is not that accurate (by design) and JS is single threaded so those two executions happen somewhere close to the next 250ms and sequentially. But in any case they happen too fast for the eye to follow, also most modern browsers do batch rendering as an optimization step so the change may not happen at all.

**===**

But because you mentioned you're not familiar with react and this is a hands on exercise I'd say that you can do some changes to write this better (in react terms). See the example below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Timer</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      const merge = (x, y) => Object.assign({}, x, y)
      class GameDisplay extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = { 
            fill: props.primaryFill,
            secondsElapsed: 0 
          }
          this.tick = this.tick.bind(this)
          this.colorChange = this.colorChange.bind(this)
        }

        tick() {
          this.colorChange();
          this.setState((prevState) => merge(prevState, {
            secondsElapsed: prevState.secondsElapsed + 1,
          }));
          setTimeout(this.colorChange, 250)
          setTimeout(this.colorChange, 500)
          setTimeout(this.colorChange, 750)
        }

        colorChange() {
          this.setState((prevState, props) => {
            const { primaryFill, secondaryFill } = props
            const oldFill = this.state.fill
            const fill = oldFill === primaryFill ? secondaryFill : primaryFill
            return merge(prevState, { fill })
          })
        }

        componentDidMount() {
          this.tick()
          this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
        }

        componentWillUnmount(){
          clearInterval(this.interval);
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1>Seconds Elapsed: {this.state.secondsElapsed}</h1>
              <svg id="main_disp" width="300" height="300">
                <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="50" fill="black" />
                <circle id="heart" cx="150" cy="150" r="30" fill={this.state.fill} />
              </svg>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      function App() {
        return (
          <div>
            <GameDisplay primaryFill="red" secondaryFill="green" />
          </div>
        )
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some highlighted best practices:

1. don't mutate the DOM, react favors a unidirectional flow of data, as in `action > state > view`, see https://medium.com/@khbrt/react-unidirectional-data-flow-explained-71bc35858226 (there are exceptions to this for intensive animations but as a general rule try to avoid it)
2. in case you have to mutate it, try to get elements using the refs API instead of `document.getElementById`, see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
3. use functional components if there are no reasons for class ones,
   see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html
4. code may get cleaner if you use some ES6+ features,
   see https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus

Comment: Mehiel thank you very much for your time and the references, this is a big help.  Thank you.